# ignoring changes in committed files in git

Tags: git, readonly, gitignore

I got some files in my repo that can be changed during the development, but I don't want to commit the changes in those files. In another words, those files should be read-only files inside my git.
The question is, how can I make `git status` ignoring them? AFAIU, .gitignore isn't fitted for this task.
(There are many such files - they being changed automatically by a script)

Comment: How about: `git update-index --assume-unchanged filename`

Comment: Great! and how can I update this configuration on the remote repo (so I won't need to do this for every local-clone)?

Comment: That's the problem. You can't

Comment: Damn...
I'll add this comment to the "problematic" script. 
Tnx